# While Using POST API of Wiki Confluence getting 403 error

Tags: javascript, wiki, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to consume wiki Confluence API, **GET** working fine, URL I am using is :

wiki/rest/api/content/327704??status=draft

but while trying to update the page content by using this API as per documentation:

wiki/rest/api/content/327704?status=draft

Method : "PUT"

```
{
    "id": "327704",
    "status": "current",
    "version": {
        "number": 2
    },
    "space": {
        "key": "TST"
    },
    "type": "page",
    "title": "Test",
    "body": {
        "storage": {
            "value": "<p>Test Page</p>",
            "representation": "storage"
        }
    }
}
```

getting 403 with error :

```
{
    "error": "Failed to parse Connect Session Auth Token"
}
```

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Referring DOC Link:

https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/6.6.0/

Comment: Sounds like you need a Connect Session Auth Token... Looks like there's a [Security section in the documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/security-overview/)

Comment: @HereticMonkey which option I need to select to pass the auth token in postman.Thanks!

Comment: Using query string: `GET https://<my-dev-environment>.atlassian.net/jira/rest/api/2/issue/AC-1.json?jwt=<jwt-token>` or using headers: `POST https://<my-dev-environment>.atlassian.net/jira/rest/api/2/issue/AC-1/attachments` and `"Authorization" header value: "JWT <jwt-token>"`. You can also go to this page and click "run in postman" on the top right - https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/

Comment: @AlexGelinas I am using CURL to get curl -u Key:AKXrcRZHZfOQdbwF3it5689E -X GET, able to get data with postman also, but while trying to update same data getting 403, adding this key and value in header, but still same..Could you please suggest.

Comment: Are you still using GET to do that? It should probably be a POST or a PUT =]